# Expression Studio not prompting for serial

Tags: installation, expression-blend

I had a msdn registered copy of Expression Studio installed on my machine and recently got a paid licensed copy.  I uninstalled it and removed what I could find in the registry that looked related.  However every time I try to install Expression to use my new license it doesn't prompt and just installs.  It appears that somewhere the old registration code is being stored somewhere however I am unable to find where.

**Solution**: In the Expression applications under Help there is a menu item titled "Enter Product Key"

Comment: Duplicated on SuperUser - http://superuser.com/questions/57318/expression-studio-not-prompting-for-serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Expression applications under Help there is a menu item titled "Enter Product Key"

Answer (score 0):

I never got prompted for expression studio installing it for the first time? Plus in the long run as long as you own a license you are good to go.